# How can I display one json file in two Tabulator tables on one HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I would like to create one html page, which shows two Tabulator tables. These two tables are connected and show the data from one json file (when the first table is full, the json data continues in the second table).

My current problem is, that my HTML code just shows one table and not two. So far the code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCSS.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="idTable"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="saveFile.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableDesign.js"></script>

<div id="idTable"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="saveFile.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableDesign.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried different ways like:

- just a second `<div id="idTable"></div>` below the first one
- just a second `<div id="idTable"></div>` below the two `<script>`
- seperating both tables by giving the second div the id `idTable2` and creating copied files, so that `idTable2` is connected to `saveFile2.sjon` and `tableDesign2.js`

How can I solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: what do you define as "full" in the first table ? There is no inherent mechanism to do what you are asking (you definitely need 2 different ID's for each table tho). I have tables side by side and populate the right based on activity on the left, but you have to write the functions to do it yourself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. By "full" I mean: Table 1 has for example 10 rows, but the json file has an array with 20 objects, so object 11-20 are displayed in table 2. So far I haven't found something like "just show 10 rows" in the Tabulator docs.

Comment: What would you like to do if the data has 30 rows in it ? Just trying to get a picture before I do a jsfiddle

Comment: To stay in the example of "2 tables with each 10 rows to display data": If the json had content for 30 rows, the rows 21+ would just stay hidden. Kinda like a Top 20 charts list of music singles. Visually it ends at place 20, but in the background the json can grow to whatever length and updates itself, because new singles get released and positions of singles change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h8a26zsv/1/